# Iterate through pages but its not happening

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

I need to iterate through the pages and get the result. Kindly have a look at the code , is there any thing I'm doing wrong .

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.pakwheels.com/used-cars/search/-/?page="

for page in range(10):

    print('---', page, '---')

    r = requests.get(url + str(page))


soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

all_data = []
for ul in soup.select("ul.search-vehicle-info-2"):
    car_name = ul.find_previous("h3").get_text(strip=True)
    info = [li.get_text(strip=True) for li in ul.select("li")]
    all_data.append([car_name, *info])

df = pd.DataFrame(
    all_data, columns=["Car Name", "Year", "KM", "Type", "CC", "Type 2"]
)
print(df)
df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
```

It need to start from page=1 and end at the given range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To correct the code, move `all_data` top and fix the indentation:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.pakwheels.com/used-cars/search/-/?page="

all_data = []
for page in range(1, 11):
    print("---", page, "---")
    r = requests.get(url + str(page))

    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

    for ul in soup.select("ul.search-vehicle-info-2"):
        car_name = ul.find_previous("h3").get_text(strip=True)
        info = [li.get_text(strip=True) for li in ul.select("li")][:5]
        all_data.append([car_name, *info])

df = pd.DataFrame(
    all_data, columns=["Car Name", "Year", "KM", "Type", "CC", "Type 2"]
)
print(df)
df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
```

Saves `data.csv` (screenshot from LibreOffice):

[image]